# datatable.draw(); not working in jQuery and Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I have a datatable whereby upon adding or updating a specific record in it automatically updates the row without table refresh.

I have been able to achieve all that but when it comes to updating the datatable row it doesn't work. I am using `table.draw()`, but it doesn't fire up. I have initialized the datatable accordingly but when I run the `draw()` code it doesn't work.

Where might I be going wrong?

```js
var propertycatstable = $('#propertycategorytable').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverside: true,
  ajax: "{{ route('get_propertycategories') }}",
  columns: [{
    data: 'id'
  }, {
    data: 'propertycat_title'
  }, {
    data: 'status',
    "render": function(data, type, row) {

      if (row.status == '1') {
        return 'Active';
      } else {
        return 'In_Active';
      }
    }

  }, {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false,
    searchable: false
  }, ]
});

// add a new property category
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-title').html('Create A New Property Category');
  $('.save_button').html('Save Property Category');

  var form = $('#propertcat_form')[0];

  $('.save_button').click(function() {
    $('.error_messages').html('');

    var formdata = new FormData(form);
    console.log(formdata);

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ route("storepropertycat") }}',
      method: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: formdata,
      success: function(response) {
        alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
        alertify.success(response.success);
        propertycatstable.draw(); //this is the code that isn't firing
        $('.propertycategory').modal('hide');
        console.log(response)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no error comes up

Comment: What is `propertycatstable`? Is it correct?

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes..its the variable that  defines the datatable

Comment: @geertjanknapen what might the problem here i haven't found a solution

Comment: @stephenwaweru99 is this the first time creating/drawing the datatable or are you trying to 'redraw'/refresh it? It the latter is the case, try `propertycatstable.destroy();` right before the draw() otherwise try `propertycatstable.rows().invalidate().draw()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing a thorough research and digging deep table.draw(); works on certain datatables..i used this code and it perfectly works **propertycatstable.ajax.reload();**